# Mounting a container volume into another container on a different path

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to mount a volume from a container into another container on a different path? E.g.

- `contA` exposes a volumen `/source`
- mounting it in another container `docker run --volumes-from contA -v /source/somedir:/etc/otherdir`

I'm trying to use this with `docker-compose` and [`jwilder/nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy):

*docker-compose.yml*

```
myapp:
  build: .
  command: ./run.sh
  volumes:
    - /source

nginx:
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
  volumes_from:
    - myapp
  volumes:
    - /source/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:ro
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
  links:
    - myapp:myapp
```

If I'm trying so, I can't see my files at `/etc/nginx/vhost.d`:

```
$ docker-compose run nginx bash                                  
root@f200c1c476c7:/app# ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1076 Apr  9 22:10 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1079 Apr  9 22:10 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  129 Apr  9 22:10 Procfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8385 Apr  9 22:10 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5493 Apr  9 22:10 nginx.tmpl
root@f200c1c476c7:/app# ls -l /etc/nginx/vhost.d
total 0
root@f200c1c476c7:/app# ls -l /source/nginx/
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 staff 957 Apr 24 07:17 dockerhost.me
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible, considering the syntax `- v /host/path:/container/path` is reserved for mounting a path from host (and not from another container)

That leaves you with the option of adding to your second container a symbolic link from `/etc/otherdir` to `/source/somedir` (which will exist because of the `--volumes-from contA` directive)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, but that would mean I've to "modify" my second container, what is possible. But I hoped I don't have to :)

Comment: @sspross modifiy your second container Dockerfile indeed. But if it is already running, you simply can add the symlink dynamically (`docker exec`).

Comment: Ok thanks, didn't know that. But if I'm using a deployment orchestration like tutum, there is no 'easy' way to run `docker exec` at some 'good' point... Maybe I have to create another image based on jwilder/nginx-proxy for my project...

Comment: @sspross if you have access to the host where the second container is running, you can type it manually.

Comment: yeah but that's not valid deployment option for me, I don't want to do this things by hand. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @sspross Why your tutum script could not add a `docker exec` step (after starting the containers)?